# Cmd makes a "beep" every time I input 7

Tags: visual-c++

When I execute this, every time I input 7 the PC makes a "beep". Can someone explain me why? I use this header: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

```
int main()
{
    double d = 0;
    while (cin >> d){
        int i = d;
        char c = i;
        int i2 = c;
        cout << "d==" << d
            << " i==" << i
            << " i2==" << i2
            << " char==(" << c << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII character 7 is the [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) dating back to the ancient days of teletype...